# pass code behind variable value to link in aspx

Tags: asp.net

I have value in variable in code behind file. I want to pass that value to link present in aspx page. this is my code behind file code.

```
  string SchoolCode = Request.QueryString["School_Code"].ToString();
```

This is my aspx page.

```
 <a  href="ProgressReportSchool.aspx?School_Code=<%# Eval("SchoolCode") %>">See Progress Report</a>
```

I want to show progressreportschool.aspx with the url in the link by passing schoolcode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this in server-side

See Progress Report

Code Behind(VB.Net)

```
Private Sub aprogress_ServerClick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles aprogress.ServerClick
        aprogress.HRef = "ProgressReportSchool.aspx?" & SchoolCode 
End Sub
```